# Why is insert not a function here?

Tags: mongodb, insert

dnp.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: db.collection(...).insert is not a function
    at addBusiness (dnp.js:5)

```
function addBusiness() {
db.collection("businesses").insert({owner_id : client.authedId(), 
                                     city: "mycity", 
                                     county: "mycounty", 
                                     name: "mybusiness", 
                                     state: "myState",
                                     street: "mystreet",
                                     zip: "myzip"});
```

}

Comment: Read this:https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mongodb-typeerror-db-collection-is-not-a-function/285588/2

Comment: Assuming you're using the official nodejs mongo drivers (if not, please specify). The docs show collection.insert() was deprecated, have you tried using insertOne() instead?

Comment: Yes I did, couldn't that to work either.